# Rebooting after Ubuntu installation brings me to grub command line

Tags: boot

I reinstalled Ubuntu, and on rebooting after the installation, it brought me to the grub command line with the texts

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub> _
```

The reason I had to reinstall Ubuntu was because I was having a login loop, where trying  log in to the system brings be back to the login page again and again, instead of actually logging me in. And all the fixes I found online couldn't solve the problem. One of the fixes I tried before re-installing Ubuntu was Installing `lightdm` and later removing and installing gdm3 again, as lightdm did not also solve my problem.

My main problem now is being able to boot and not meet the grub command line.

Comment: Which release number did you install?

Answer (score -1):

Likely grub isn't aware of where your installation is located and you'll have to use bash commands to locate the partition and flag it as the boot partition in grub. You need to update your grub.cfg with the missing info

Edit: First I would boot your live usb and in terminal use chroot to gain root on your installed system, and run the command update-grub , if that doesnt work then that's when I would mess with grub.cfg using vim